# Weird fix from PageSpeed Tools

Tags: html, optimization, character-encoding, character, meta-tags

When I test my webpage in PageSpeed Tools (a tool to optimize webpages by Google), I get these problems:

Problem #1:

> **Avoid a character set in the meta tag**
>
> The following resources have a character set specified in a meta tag.
>   Specifying a character set in a meta tag disables the lookahead downloader in IE8.
>   To improve resource download parallelization, move the character set to the HTTP Content-Type response header.

Problem #2:

> **Specify a character set**
>
> Specifying a character set early for your HTML documents allows the browser to Begin executing scripts IMMEDIATELY.
>
> *Suggestions for this page*
>
> The following resources have not set the character set in HTTP headers.
>   If you specify a character set in there, speeds up the rendering in the browser.

But I do not see why I get these problems because I have specified Character set like this in the head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-15" />
```

**The question:** Can someone help me fix these problems?

Comment: I think what it may be referring to setting the charset in the back-end.  Here's more info on that: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations

Comment: So, since I use HTML5 I would want to write `<meta charset="iso-8859-15">`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's telling you: Move the character set to the HTTP Content-Type response header. Look at this:

> [Wikipedia - List of HTTP header fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields.)

Basically, the actual HTTP response that the client gets back from the server, should have the **Content-Type** field set. If you can't change this, then just set it in the `<meta>` tag as you are.

**EDIT:**

If you are able to, modify the .htaccess file on the server to include:

> AddType 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-15' html

That will cause all the HTML files served to include the appropriate response header.

Comment: Where is the site being served from?

Comment: Do you have control over the server? Are you able to modify the .htaccess file?

Comment: But I have set the character set. Why is it giving me an error, then?

Comment: It's not an error! It's a hint to speed up your page. It would be *better* to have it set in the Response Header, but it's fine for it to be set in the document head.